how to stop visual studio from autocompleting #if with #endif in C++
when you type '#if', and autocompletion popup gets shown:

and upon pression 'tab' here, the code gets completed to

How do I stop visual studio from doing this ?

This feature is IntelliSense, if you do not want it to show the autocomplete popup window, you can uncheck the "Auto list members" option and "Parameter information" option. This option is usually found in Text Editor > All Languages > General.

I do want auto-complete popup, I just don't want it to auto-complete closing #endif

I have searched for a long time in VS, and it seems that there is no such function. Maybe you should look for some extensions to implement this function.
